# Perforce - is it possible to directly submit open files on a different branch?

Tags: integration, perforce

I'm using perforce for versioning control. Let's say I am working on a file in the main branch:
`//main/xx.cs` (it's open for edit)

In the mean time, `//main` gets branched to `//v1` and then `//main` gets *locked*. 
Is there a way I can integrate my local changes in `//main/xx.cs` directly to `//v1/xx.cs` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question: [Can I integrate checked out files into a different branch on perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300160/can-i-integrate-checked-out-files-into-a-different-branch-on-perforce)

One of the answers there gives:
http://kb.perforce.com/UserTasks/CodelinesAndBranching/BranchingWorkInProgress
which looks like it will provide more than you need.

There is also various p4shelve, p4tar options that might help:

1. [P4 Shelve](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4_Shelve) Python addition for any version of Perforce
2. [P4tar](http://public.perforce.com/wiki/P4tar) offline (or at least off-server) saving of changes
3. [p4 shelve](http://blog.perforce.com/blog/?p=1872) 2009.2 and later Perforce feature to provide built-in shelving.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility...

- Sync //main to the changelist where the branch was made. Resolve conflicts.
- Important! Sync //v1 to the same changelist.
- Open //v1/xx.cs for edit.
- The ugly part: manually copy the local copy of //main/xx.cs over the local copy of //v1/xx.cs
- Sync //v1 to head and resolve conflicts.
- Submit changes.

Voila!